# Design pattern for accepting stdin OR CLI arguments

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, stdin, argv

For C++, how do I accept CLI arguments *or* stdin?

For instance, let's say I have a function `foo()` that I want to call over a variable number of arguments. For standard args, I simply use something like:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cout << "usage goes here.\n";
    } else {
        for (int i; i < argc; ++i) {
            foo(argv[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

But what if they sent them to me via stdin and piped the parameters to my application? Is there a way to detect and accept/handle both? What is an efficient design pattern to do this in modern C++ (C++11 and beyond)?

I'm interested in the design pattern / sample implementation. Feel free to reference a library that does this (Boost?) but please share/explain an example implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would only read *input* from stdin, not arguments/options. By reading and evaluating arguments/options, the program should decide if it expects input from stdin or e.g. a file argument.

As example from the [manpage of grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep):

> **Synopsis**
>
> grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]
>
> **Description**
>
> grep searches the named input FILEs (or standard input if **no files** are named, or if a single **hyphen-minus (-) is given** as file name) for lines containing a match to the given PATTERN.

A lack of the FILE argument or the - option indicates *grep* to read stdin.

Invokation of your program could look like this, the lack of the file argument indicates reading input from stdin:

```
# file argument, input is in the file
command -o someoption filename

# file content supplied via stdin
command -o someoption < filename     

# with pipe and - (stdin) as file argument
othercommand | command -o someoption -
```

For parsing options/arguments boost has the [program options library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/program_options.html)